# Javascript - Unable to calculate product price correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in my vue app and it is supposed to calculate the cost of a product when it's added to the cart.

```js
    calculatePartial(productInfo, productPrice, productCode, productUnit){            
        let val = productInfo.match(/[0-9]/g)
        let portion
        let multiplier
        //
        if( val.length > 2 ){
            portion = `${val[0]}${val[1]}${val[2]}`
        } else if( val.length === 1 ) { 
            portion = `${val[0]}`
        } else {
            portion = `${val[0]},${val[1]}`
        }
        if( portion === '500' ){
            return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 2 ).toFixed(2)
        } else if( portion === '300' ){ 
            return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 1000 * 300 ).toFixed(2)
        } else if( portion === '600' ){
            return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 1000 * 600 ).toFixed(2)
        } else if( portion === '800' ){
            return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 1000 * 800 ).toFixed(2)
        } else if( portion === '1' ) {
            return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode])).toFixed(2)
        } else {
                multiplier = portion.replace(',', '.')
            if( productUnit === 'al pz' ){
                return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode])).toFixed(2)
            } else if( productUnit === "all'etto" ){
                return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 100 * multiplier ).toFixed(2)
            } else {     
                if( multiplier.length > 2 && !multiplier.includes('.') ){
                    return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 1000 * multiplier).toFixed(2) 
                } else {   
                    return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) * multiplier).toFixed(2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have some problems with it, during tests I've noticed that I'm unable to get the correct price calculation if a product weight is different from the weight I have inside the `if` and `else if` code blocks. I've tried to fix it but it's not the best solution

```js
                if( multiplier.length > 2 && !multiplier.includes('.') ){
                    return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) / 1000 * multiplier).toFixed(2) 
                } else {   
                    return (parseFloat(productPrice) * parseInt(this.quantita[productCode]) * multiplier).toFixed(2)
                }
```

How I can fix the code to get a correct calculation without the `if` `else if` and `else` blocks? It will be ideal that using the product information the calculation can be dono indipendently from the weight. Thank you for the help

Comment: At a glance, it looks like there are a lot of style issues in the code (repetition of the same statement, nested if..else, iteration instead of parameterization, type issues, fuzzy logic). No wonder this goes awry at some point. I would start by fixing those issues. If it helps you, I can write out an answer with some pointers, but you might be better off asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It will help improve the code, this is an old versione and I need to improve it.!